# Python: String filter

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need help in python. I need to find my code in this -->

```
<li class="hide" style="display: list-item;">
    <div class="name">Name</div>
    <span class="value">TEST TEST</span>
</li>
```

These words:Name, TEST TEST.

Comment: Are you using beautifulSoup?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what code you have tried so far and any specific errors you are running into?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I'm using beautifulSoup.

Comment: To put it bluntly, I only tried searching the Internet, but I found nothing that could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `find` method in bs4

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<li class="hide" style="display: list-item;">
    <div class="name">Name</div>
    <span class="value">TEST TEST</span>
</li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print( soup.find("li", class_="hide").text.strip() )
```

**Output:**

```
Name
TEST TEST
```

- After you find the required element use `.text` to extract the string.